# Retreive data from server onClick View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I have a server that I get data from and display on a `RecyclerView`, When I click on the view, it is expected to open another activity that will display the full detail of the specific view, therefore the Id of the post is used to get the full content. I passed the id by intent to the new Activity, am getting an error:
`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 34, size is 0`
how do I make the Api call to get the content using id?

This is the full content for the item with id=34

```
{
  "blog_id": "34",
  "blog_title": "BLOG TITLE",
  "blog_subtitle": "Inspiration for Article Intro Effects",
  "blog_excerpt": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, veniam vidisse periculis ei mel, an nam malis nostrud euripidis. Ad invidunt explicari repudiandae qui, ut quo dolor sadipscing. Est laudem offendit ei. Id mentitum asse",
  "blog_content": "<p>We may define a food to be any substance which will repair the functional waste of the body, increase its growth, or maintain the heat, muscular, and nervous energy.</p>\r\n<p>In its most comprehensive sense, the oxygen of the air is a food; as although it is admitted by the lungs, it passes into the blood, and there re-acts upon the other food which has passed through the stomach. It is usual, however, to restrict the term food to such nutriment as enters the body by the intestinal canal. Water is often spoken of as being distinct from food, but for this there is no sufficient reason.</p>\r\n<p>Many popular writers have divided foods into flesh-formers, heat-givers, and bone-formers. Although attractive from its simplicity, this classification will not 
  "blog_thumbnail": "https://watchnollywood.ml/app/templates/default/",
  "blog_medimg": "https://watchnollywood.ml/app/templates/default/images/medium_57d4789461f8b.jpg",
  "category_title": "General"
}
```

BlogAdapter:

```
public class MyBlogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogViewHolder> {
List<BlogPost> postsList;
List<SingleBlogPost> singleBlogPosts;
Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
static  String blog_Id;
static String blogID;

public MyBlogAdapter(Context context, List<BlogPost> postsList){
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.postsList = postsList;
}
@Override
public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog_post_item,parent, false);
    return new BlogViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BlogViewHolder holder, int position) {
    BlogPost posts= postsList.get(position);
    holder.summary.setText(posts.getBlogExcerpt().trim().toString());
    holder.title.setText(posts.getBlogTitle().trim().toString());
    Glide.with(context).load(posts.getBlogThumbnail()).into(holder.cover);

    holder.blogHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AnotherSingleView.class);
            blog_Id = posts.getBlogId();
            intent.putExtra(blogID,blog_Id);
            Log.d("MyblogAdapter","Please check blog Id: "+blog_Id);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });  
   }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("MyBlogAdapter,","getItemCount"+postsList.size());

    return postsList == null ? (0) : postsList.size();
}
}
```

AnotherSingleView:

```
public class AnotherSingleView extends AppCompatActivity {
String postID;
int position = 0;
public TextView blogTitle,blogSub,blogContent;
public ImageView blogPic;
List<SingleBlogPost> singleBlogPosts;
 SingleBlogPost singleBlogPost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another_single_view);


    Intent intent  = getIntent();
    Bundle showBlogId = intent.getExtras();
    postID = showBlogId.getString(blogID);
    Log.d("AnotherSingleView","Please check blog Id: "+postID);

    singleBlogPosts = new ArrayList<>();

    blogContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blog_content);
    blogSub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.blog_subtitle);
    blogTitle =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.blog_title);
    blogPic =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blog_pix);
    singlePostDisplay();

}

private void singlePostDisplay() {
    singleBlogPost = singleBlogPosts.get(Interger.parseInt(postID));
    String post_id = singleBlogPost.getBlogId();
    if (postID.matches(post_id)){
        BlogaPI api = ApiClient.getBlogInterface();
      Call<List<SingleBlogPost>> call = api.postResponse();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<SingleBlogPost>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<SingleBlogPost>> call, Response<List<SingleBlogPost>> response) {
               singleBlogPosts = response.body();
                blogContent.setText(singleBlogPost.getBlogContent());
                blogSub.setText(singleBlogPost.getBlogSubtitle());
                blogTitle.setText(singleBlogPost.getBlogTitle());
                Glide.with(AnotherSingleView.this).load(singleBlogPost.getBlogMedimg()).into(blogPic);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<SingleBlogPost>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface BlogRequestInterface {

  @GET("blog")
  Call<BlogApi> getMyBlog();
  @GET("post/{id}")
  Call<List<SingleBlogPost>> getSinglePost();
}
```

Pojo class:

```
public class SingleBlogPost {

@SerializedName("blog_id")
@Expose
private String blogId;
@SerializedName("blog_title")
@Expose
private String blogTitle;
@SerializedName("blog_subtitle")
@Expose
private String blogSubtitle;
@SerializedName("blog_excerpt")
@Expose
private String blogExcerpt;
@SerializedName("blog_content")
@Expose
private String blogContent;
@SerializedName("blog_thumbnail")
@Expose
private String blogThumbnail;
@SerializedName("blog_medimg")
@Expose
private String blogMedimg;
@SerializedName("category_title")
@Expose
private String categoryTitle;

public String getBlogId() {
    return blogId;
}

public void setBlogId(String blogId) {
    this.blogId = blogId;
}

public String getBlogTitle() {
    return blogTitle;
}

public void setBlogTitle(String blogTitle) {
    this.blogTitle = blogTitle;
}

public String getBlogSubtitle() {
    return blogSubtitle;
}

public void setBlogSubtitle(String blogSubtitle) {
    this.blogSubtitle = blogSubtitle;
}

public String getBlogExcerpt() {
    return blogExcerpt;
}

public void setBlogExcerpt(String blogExcerpt) {
    this.blogExcerpt = blogExcerpt;
}

public String getBlogContent() {
    return blogContent;
}

public void setBlogContent(String blogContent) {
    this.blogContent = blogContent;
}

public String getBlogThumbnail() {
    return blogThumbnail;
}

public void setBlogThumbnail(String blogThumbnail) {
    this.blogThumbnail = blogThumbnail;
}

public String getBlogMedimg() {
    return blogMedimg;
}

public void setBlogMedimg(String blogMedimg) {
    this.blogMedimg = blogMedimg;
}

public String getCategoryTitle() {
    return categoryTitle;
}

public void setCategoryTitle(String categoryTitle) {
    this.categoryTitle = categoryTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend adding ClickListeners on onBindViewHolder. My onCreateViewHolder does something like this.

```
   @Override
   public BlogViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog_post_item,parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do stuff
        }
    });

    return new BlogViewHolder(view);
}
```

And if you need position or list object for that you can refer to this link http://androidshenanigans.blogspot.com.tr/2015/02/viewholder-pattern-common-mistakes.html

Hope it helps.